# 3 Static IPs, 1 Modem, 1 Dual WAN TP-Link Router

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, ip-routing

Can I place a hub/non-L3 switch between my Router and Cable modem to utilize the other IPs?  I'm interested in using one of the IPs for Direct Access.

Thanks

Comment: If cable modem works as bridge then you can use switch for this. If not then you need to reconfigure modem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Most ISP allow that. You could even link 3 router to that switch to use those 3 IPs.

Some thompson modem will allow only 3 IP out per modem, as such you should be fine without adding more modem